# perform onclick event in reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to make an application using reactjs.below is the code which present in my main app.js:

```
class App extends Component {
    return (
        <div>
            <ExampleTable
                header={() => <TopBar/>}
            />
            <AddExampleModal/>
            <ChartModal/>
            <CompatibilityAlert/>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

where Top Bat,AddExampleModal , ChartModal and CompatibilityAlert are loaded from other js files.

Chartmodal contains:

```
class ChartModal extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props)
}

render(){
    return(
        <Modal
            onOk={()=>console.log('ok')}
            onCancel={()=>console.log('cancel')}
            visible={true}
            okText={'ok'}
            cancelText={'cancel'}
            confirmLoading={false}
            title="Intent distribution chart"
        >
            <h1>HOWDY</h1>
            <TreeMap
                data={chartData}
                width={400}
                valueUnit={'count'}
            />
        </Modal>
    )
  }
}
```

Topbar contains :

```
class TopBar extends Component {
    render{
            return (
            <Button
                style={styles.button}
                type='primary'
               // onClick={() => changechartshow()}
            >
                Show Graph
            </Button>
           )
         }
      }
```

The thing is that in the app file,i want to toggle the visibility of chartmodal using the button in the topbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App

```
class App extends Component {

    constructor() {
        this.state = {
          isVisible: true
        }
    }

    toggleVisibility = () => this.setState({isVisible: !this.state.isVisible})
    render () {

        const {isVisible} = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <ExampleTable
                    header={() => <TopBar toggleVisibility =
                                {this.toggleVisibility.bind(this)}
                          />}
                <AddExampleModal/>
                <ChartModal isVisible={isVisible}/>
                <CompatibilityAlert/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

TopBar

```
class TopBar extends Component {
    render{
        return (
        <Button
            style={styles.button}
            type='primary'
            onClick={() => this.props.toggleVisibility()}
        >
            Show Graph
        </Button>
       )
     }
  }
```

ChartModal - Pass the state to visible attribute

```
class ChartModal extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props)
}

render(){
    return(
        <Modal
            onOk={()=>console.log('ok')}
            onCancel={()=>console.log('cancel')}
            visible={this.props.isVisible}
            okText={'ok'}
            cancelText={'cancel'}
            confirmLoading={false}
            title="Intent distribution chart"
        >
            <h1>HOWDY</h1>
            <TreeMap
                data={chartData}
                width={400}
                valueUnit={'count'}
            />
        </Modal>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: how will the topbar know about the togglevisibility function. because we are not passing the function so that we can receive using props?

Comment: oh apologies, anyways thanks for edit but not sure if you need to bind toggleVisibility function since its an arrow function

Answer (score 1):

You can add a state in your `App` component and pass an `handler` to update the state from the `TopBar` component. Based on this state you can toggle the visibility of `ChartModal`.

```
class App extends Component {
    state = {
      isVisible: true
    }
    toggleVisibility = () => {
       this.setState(prevState => ({isVisible: !prevState.isVisible}))
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <ExampleTable
                header={() => <TopBar toggleVisibility={this.toggleVisibility}/>}
            />
            <AddExampleModal/>
            {this.state.isVisible ? <ChartModal/>: null }
            <CompatibilityAlert/>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Now in your TopBar you will call this function as

```
class TopBar extends Component {
    render{
        return (
        <Button
            style={styles.button}
            type='primary'
            onClick={() => this.props.toggleVisibility()}
        >
            Show Graph
        </Button>
       )
     }
  }
```

Read the React docs here on [**Lifting the state up**](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) for a detailed explanation